# How to get the coordinates of all blue pixels with matplotlib imread?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, imread

I would like to append to a list all of the blue pixels of a jpeg image using matplolib's imshow. When I launch my code, I do not get an RGB code result:'array([89, 67, 28], dtype=uint8), array([51, 53, 16], dtype=uint8),' etc... What is going wrong here?

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

```
control = mpimg.imread('jpeg.jpg')
ys = control.shape[0] #length of image
xs = control.shape[1] # image width
pixelcoords= []
for x in range(xs):
    for y in range(ys):
        # if pixel is blue
        pixelcoords.append(control[x][y])

print(pixelcoords)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading an image you will get an numpy array of the dimensions (width x height x [R,G,B, alpha]).

```
t = mpimg.imread("path/Test1.PNG")
```

now you can just access the blue layer by taking everything along the width and height dimension (indicated by the ":") and only the 3rd dimension from the RGB,alpha stack. that gives you a 2D array, where every blue pixel has a nonzero value. to find all the coordinates of nonzero entries you can use the np.nonzero function, which gives you their coordinates as an X and Y array

```
X,Y = np.nonzero(t[:,:,2])
```

Comment: Thank you. This returns me the coordinates of all of the blue pixels. I'm interested in obtaining only the bluest pixels. How can I get the values of the blue pixels though? The returned array only provides the coordinates: (array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 447, 447, 447], dtype=int64), array([112, 113, 114, ..., 381, 382, 383], dtype=int64))

Comment: What do you mean by "bluest"? the ones where the value for blue is higher than the ones for red and green? or higher than for red and green combined? or above a certain threshold? or the most blue in all the image?